# what does Y-axis represents in perform metric collector graph

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have performed server monitoring test on my test server. Now looking on to the graph mapped over Perform Metric Collector listener, i have been struggling to understand the coordinates name and the graph.

[image: 1]

Comment: Can anyone please help on this ...?

Answer (score 0):

Network I/O measured by [Transmission time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_time) and CPU by [CPU Usage Time](https://github.com/Leo-G/DevopsWiki/wiki/How-Linux-CPU-Usage-Time-and-Percentage-is-calculated).

Your image display network IO and CPU which is cover in [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/):

> Some example metric parameter strings:
>
> ``` ### CPU ### combined - measure total CPU usage, equals to 100-idle value core=2:user - measure user process CPU usage for third core in system (core numbering starts at 0) name=java#2:user - will monitor second java process instance for user time spent pid=14523:percent - will monitor process with PID 14523 for total CPU usage percentage name=httpd - omitting metric type will use default 'percent'
>
> #### Network IO ### iface=eth0:tx - will monitor interface eth0 for transmitted packet rate ```

Comment: That means the Y-axis metric represents number of Users/Sec for #CPU. It would be more helpful if you can elaborate you post . i am still in a confusing state.

Comment: Any help on this, as i am struggling to understand the graph.

Comment: add more info to answer